# iOS Charts Library - How to handle X-Axis duplicate values

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I have used Charts library by @danielgindi to generate the graph for my iOS application. All seems works fine but we are facing issue with X-Axis data duplication.

**Input Data for Graph in (X-Axis-Value, Y-Axis-Value)**

("29/03/2017 00:00:00","2.7")

("29/03/2017 00:00:00","2.4")

("29/03/2017 00:10:00","1.3")

("29/03/2017 00:10:00","1.5")

("29/03/2017 00:20:00","1.8")

....

....

....

("29/03/2017 01:00:00","1.2")

("29/03/2017 09:00:00","2.7")

("29/03/2017 09:10:00","-10.8")

....

....

....

("29/03/2017 13:10:00","3.9")

("29/03/2017 13:20:00","-.8")

("29/03/2017 13:20:00","5.9"

Where X-Axis value is date time and Y Axis value is Double value associated to that date-time.

I have used following code for the **formatting X-Axis**

```
class ChartStringFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    public func stringForValue(_ value: TimeInterval, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
        return date.toString(format: "hh:mm a")
    }
}
```

But when I zoom the graph it has multiple values for X-Axis. How should I resolved this issues?

**Expected Output For X Axis Value:**

Initially - [12:00 AM, 03:00 AM, 06:00 AM, 09:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 03:00 PM, 06:00 PM, 09:00 PM, 12:00 PM]

When Zoom - [12:00 AM, 01:00 AM, 02:00 AM, 03:00 AM ...... 12:00 PM]

Again Zoom - [12:00 AM, 12:30 AM, 01:00 AM, 01:30AM, 02:00 AM, 02:30 AM, 03:00 AM ...... 12:00 PM]

Again Again Zoom - [12:00 AM, 12:10 AM, 12:20 AM, 12:30 AM ...... 12:00 PM]

**[Sample GIF file:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0wtzpf7s35bo9j/sample.gif?dl=0)**

iOS Charts Library Link: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in iOS-Charts library documentation:

> When true, axis labels are controlled by the `granularity` property.
>
> When false, axis values could possibly be repeated.
>
> ...
>
> `@property (nonatomic) BOOL granularityEnabled;`

and:

> The minimum interval between axis values.
>
> This can be used to avoid label duplicating when zooming in.
>
> *default*: 1.0
>
> `@property (nonatomic) double granularity;`

So Im pretty sure that those lines will do the work for you:

`[yourChart.xAxis setGranularityEnabled:YES];`

`[yourChart.xAxis setGranularity:1.0];`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following two properties in your chart then it will solve your problem

```
chart.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
chart.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

Remember not to use this property in your chart if you want to remove duplication

```
chart.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
```

Comment: How use "chart.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true" in swiftui ?

Comment: @KaayZenn Look into following medium article https://medium.com/geekculture/multiline-chart-in-swiftui-ios-charts-deef23bb32aa