# Repeating values on x-axis for iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using the [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and I'm getting a repeating labels on my x-axis.
[image]

I'm getting numerous answers ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667519/10116367), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57327636/10116367), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919514/10116367)) that I should set the granularity settings:

```swift
xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

but, when I do the labels on the x-axis simply disappear.

[image]

My settings for the x-axis:

```swift
let xAxis = lineChartView.xAxis
xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
xAxis.labelFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
xAxis.setLabelCount(6, force: false)
xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 0.4)
xAxis.gridColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 0.4)
xAxis.valueFormatter = ChartXAxisFormatter()
```

I've created a custom class to format the values being passed to the x-axis on the advise of the [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/):

```swift
class ChartXAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MM/dd")
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to @aiwiguna and with the help from the Charts [repo](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2094#issuecomment-273496178), I was able to create a custom class that takes in two things: a date (Double) and a corresponding index (Int), instead of just the date.

```swift
class ChartXAxisFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    private var dates: [Double]?
    
    convenience init(usingDates dateArr: [Double]) {
        self.init()
        self.dates = dateArr
    }
    
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        print("value: \(value)")
        print("dates: \(dates)")
        let index = Int(value)
    
        guard let dates = dates, index < dates.count else {
            return "?"
        }
        
        let date = dates[index]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MM/dd")
        let formattedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date.rounded())
        return dateFormatter.string(from: formattedDate)
    }
}
```

The idea is to have an array of dates, `[1598409060.0, 1598409060.0]`, and returning them one by one by accessing it with an index.  Logging the `value` and `index` does show this to be the case.

The problem is, while the number of repeating labels have been reduced to match the number of plots, the duplicates still remain:

[image]

There two plots should both be stacked on top of each other on one x-axis label "8/25".

I'm using `enumerated()` to extract the index for `ChartDataEntry`:

```swift
var dateArr = [Double]()
for (index, fetchedMetric) in fetchedMetrics.enumerated() {
    let date = fetchedMetric.date.timeIntervalSince1970
    dateArr.append(date)
    if var yValues = metricDict[fetchedMetric.unit] {
        yValues.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(truncating: fetchedMetric.value)))
        metricDict.updateValue(yValues, forKey: fetchedMetric.unit)
    } else {
        metricDict.updateValue([ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(truncating: fetchedMetric.value))], forKey: fetchedMetric.unit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because when you set your chart setup (granurality = 1 and ChartXAxisFormatter) is showing each second in xAxis

I prefer to use array date to show day in axis, with something like this

```
public class DateValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private let dates:[Date]
    
    init(dates: [Date]) {
        self.dates= dates
        super.init()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm"
    }
    
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if value >= 0 && value < objects.count{
            let date = dates[Int(value)]
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }   
        return ""
    }
}
```

if you don't want to change your value formatted you can try to set granularity to 86400 (total seconds in 1 day)

Comment: @Kevvv you need to have the same x value for the same day

Comment: In the recent versions of Charts, the value is the time interval since 1970 that makes this solution not work. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid receiving repeated values, we have to create a new var in this case  `minimalTimeInterval`, which in my example is 24 hours, and always record the previously inserted value `previousValue`.

The chart before the change:
[image: Chart before the change]

The chart after thechange:
[image: Chart after the change]

Code:

```
public class DateValueFormatter: NSObject, AxisValueFormatter {
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private var previousValue: Double = 0
    private let minimalTimeInterval: Double
    
    init(dateFormatter: String, minimalTimeInterval: Double = 60 * 60 * 24) {
        self.dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormatter //"dd MMM (E)"
        self.minimalTimeInterval = minimalTimeInterval
        super.init()
    }
    
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let delta = value - previousValue
        if(delta >= minimalTimeInterval || delta < 0) {
            previousValue = value
            return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```